# How to offset the message displayed in an empty table view

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I would like to show a message when my table is empty. I create a UILabel and set it to backgroundView of my tableView, however I would like to offset the text from the the tableView borders. I am trying this by reducing the UILabel Width when I create the label (see the code below) but that doesn't have any effect.

[image]

```
    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

    if array.count > 0 {
        self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.SingleLine
        return array.count
    } else {
        let messageLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 20.0, y: 0, width: self.tableView.bounds.size.width - 40.0, height: self.tableView.bounds.size.height))
        messageLabel.text = "This is the message I would like to display when there is nothing returned from my model"
        messageLabel.numberOfLines = 0
        messageLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
        messageLabel.sizeToFit()

        tableView.backgroundView = messageLabel
        self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.None
    }

    return 0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Reference UITableView Class [Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableView/backgroundView)

> A table view’s background view is automatically resized to match the
>   size of the table view.

I would suggest you to use [DZNEmptyDataSet](https://github.com/dzenbot/DZNEmptyDataSet)

Or implement empty view with label on top of your tableView.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your CGRect is not working is I bet because you have autolayout set. Autolayout doesn't let you make changes by CGRect in your code.

Go ahead and disable Autolayout and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Add some constraints to correctly position the label in the view. Look at the code below for inspiration, but note that it is a very quick and dirty solution. Add a `print()` in that `else` block and you'll see the block is called multiple times. You should definitely look into nicer ways of displaying the message.

```
else {

    let width = self.tableView.bounds.size.width - 40.0
    let messageLabel = UILabel()
    messageLabel.text = "This is the message I would like to display when there is nothing returned from my model"
    messageLabel.numberOfLines = 0
    messageLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center

    let widthConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint (
            item: messageLabel,
            attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Width,
            relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal,
            toItem: nil,
            attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.NotAnAttribute,
            multiplier: 1,
            constant: width
    )

    let xConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(
            item: messageLabel,
            attribute: .CenterX,
            relatedBy: .Equal,
            toItem: self.tableView,
            attribute: .CenterX,
            multiplier: 1,
            constant: 0
    )

    let yConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(
            item: messageLabel,
            attribute: .CenterY,
            relatedBy: .Equal,
            toItem: self.tableView, 
            attribute: .CenterY,
            multiplier: 0.85,
            constant: 0
    )

    self.tableView.backgroundView = messageLabel        
    self.tableView.backgroundView?.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints([widthConstraint, xConstraint, yConstraint])

    self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.None
}
```

This gives you:

[image: Screenshot of]